# Ruby subclass not inheriting parent method or not able to call parent methods in class body

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm making a page-object.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Page

  attr_accessor :driver

  def initialize
    @driver = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
    @driver.goto(some_arbitrary_url)
  end

  def element(**attrs)
    @driver.element( id: attrs[:id], tag_name: attrs[:tag_name])
  end

  def elements(**attrs)
    @driver.elements( class: attrs[:class], tag_name: attrs[:tag_name])
  end

end
```

However when I subclass the `Page` class, I cannot use it's `element` methods in the class body, unless I put them in a method, like so:

```
class Home < Page

  #throws NoMethodError: undefined method 'element' for Home:Class
  some_element = element(id: 'elements_id')

  #works
  def some_arbitrary_element
    element(id: 'elements_id')
  end

end
```

So far, just tinkering, I've tried doing `protected: element, elements` as well as `self.element(...)` both to no avail.  So what's going on?  I'm not reading anything enlightening in Matz' Ruby book about method inheritance, and usually Ruby is so unsurprising, so it's hard for me to identify where the problem actually is.

Comment: When `some_element = element(id: 'elements_id')` is executed, `self` equals `Home`, so Ruby looks for a (class) method `Home::element` and doesn't find one. When `home = Home.new; home.some_arbitrary_element` is executed, `self` equals `home`, so Ruby looks for an *instance* method `element` of the class `Home` and finds one.

Comment: Excellent reply, thanks for your input.  I suppose it makes sense that a class body's scope would be class-level and not on an instance level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling element as if it was defined as a class method. Any code that is in a class definition but not in a method definition will only be able to call class methods. One way to make the method visible from where your calling it would be to change the signature so it becomes a method of the class object.

```
class Page
  def self.element
  end
end
```

Comment: Great reply, thanks!  So as it stands I have to either define all my `elements` as methods that return Watir's element object, or turn my parent-class' respective methods into class methods?  These both seem like rather cumbersome solutions, especially for Ruby.  I suppose I could just set them as instance variables in an initialize method as well, but I hate to crowd that one up too much.

Comment: It's hard to fully understand what the page class is doing here however from the code you posted it looks like your using it as a lookup. Have you thought about using a hash map or perhaps implementing method_missing?